# Cron Expression in android

Tags: android

I want to schedule my job like "ScheduleDownload.class" using cron Exprssion

Here is my following code

```
SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();

    Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();

JobDetail jd=new JobDetail("job1","group1",ScheduleDownload.class);

CronTrigger ct=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group2",SchdExp);

sched.scheduleJob(jd,ct);

sched.start();
```

But it giving me the following error

```
03-16 09:56:21.242: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due 
to uncaught exception

03-16 09:56:21.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852): java.lang.VerifyError: org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory

03-16 09:56:21.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852):     at com.kochar.scheduler.scheduler.CronTriggerdownload(scheduler.java:65)

03-16 09:56:21.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852):     at 
com.kochar.scheduler.scheduler.onCreate(scheduler.java:50)

03-16 09:56:21.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)

03-16 09:56:21.251: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

Please help, what i have to do remove this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Quartz is compatible with Android. Anyway, you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror) on what can cause a `java.lang.VerifyError` in Android. You should at least try to process Quartz jar files with the "dx" tool that ships with the Android SDK.

Comment: Then what is other alternative i should use for scheduling  the jobs

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html. You need to make a distinction between cases when the device will go to sleep before the event is fired and short term intervals.

Comment: hi, i had serach on neet but unable to convert jar file to dex.

Comment: write a class which solve cron Expression and schedule the task using timer and its working fine for me now

Comment: @Karan Is it possible to using cron and AlarmManager together?!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the **BuzzBox SDK scheduler**, it supports a cron expression and gives you other nice features specific for Android.

http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/scheduler

Comment: Thanks for the reply i had tried do use it but it does not tell in detail how to use it...can give any Good Example how to implement Buzz scheduler... as i want to schedule my task using cron Expression

Comment: Start from the Hello World App [http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/hello-world] the full source code is available for download