# Verify error in android

Tags: android

I just converted simple geo java project in to jar file and then added the jar in lib folder in android project.how ever ,when i supposed to run i got the following error.

> java.lang.VerifyError:
>   com.simplegeo.client.AbstractSimpleGeoClient

My code is

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         SimpleGeoPlacesClient client;
         Log.v("DEBUG INFO","setting up client");
         client = SimpleGeoPlacesClient.getInstance();
         client.getHttpClient().setToken("v6twG2W4aHmXk725WryK22wUnXVSmhqT","5wvfksDtH8QSMZeKKcDXaXC3HVDfJVx2");
         Log.v("DEBUG INFO","client is set");
   }
```

how to solve this.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror 2. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html  3. http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html check these links

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android java.lang.VerifyError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: Look in the "logcat" output.  Above the VerifyError stack trace you'll see some detailed messages with "VFY" in them.  Post those here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to recompile the jar or run it through `dx` as per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror)

> Android uses a different class file
>   format. Are you running the 3rd party
>   JAR files through the "dx" tool that
>   ships with the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

move your jar file from lib to libs folder.