# I am getting this error in android

Tags: android

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com.MinngApp.Registration$4
at com.MinngApp.Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:237)
```

I am getting all the nodes values from the webservice and then insert it into the local database. 6-7 tables are giving proper response and proper data also. But after that when I am taking another nodes then I got the error.

So can anyone help me?

Comment: Not enough data. Show us code or explain in bigger detail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: what u want more If this is the error then No data will come from the webservice..

Comment: there is a url which give all the nodes..so I am getting 6-7 data nodes properly..but after that I am getting an error

Comment: so plz tell me the solution...

Answer (score 2):

Have A Look on LogCat and see what's causing the `verifyerror`. It's probably some method in a java.lang class that is not supported on the android `SDK` level you are using (for instance, `String.isEmpty()).`

Answer (score 0):

A `VerifyError` means that Android cannot find something your  `com.MinngApp.Registration` refers to. It may be related to a wrong build target (some class that exists only in a later version of the Android SDK). We need more details to know exactly what the error is.

The **cause exception from the LogCat** would be a good start. Also look at the log **above the exception** it sometimes help in finding which class can't be found and which one had the bad reference. It may contain something along the lines of:

```
WARN/dalvikvm(1052): VFY: unable to resolve .......
```