# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, android-emulator, kindle-fire

I'm testing my application on various emulators Kindle Fire, but on this tablet I have big problems. The app is always crashes with the following LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  java.lang.VerifyError: it.bisemanuDEV.mathTools.Calculator
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you using a google API such as something within Google Play Services Library. I had this with google drive and it was because I hadn't exported the required libraries or correctly referenced them since they changed the SDK version

Comment: @Boardy i get the same error when trying to run the app on api levels below 11. verify error, i removed the deprecated method also. And supress warning annotations too .. any idea why ?

Comment: @Boardy can you elaborate on that (if you remember)? I'm facing the same exact issue...

Answer (score 4):

You first look at LogCat and see what's causing the verifyerror.

`It's probably some method in a java.lang class that is not supported on the android SDK level you are using.`

for more information refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/668788/1870450). Hope this helpful to you.

Comment: Firebase reported only one device which is Android 12, latest stable API, how is it possible? all other devices from Android 6 up to Android 12 works fine (150K users)

Answer (score 1):

Some methods in your class are not supported on a lower version of SDK that you might be using. Remove any @Supresslint or @targetApi annotations that you might have over your class or a particular method in your class and eclipse will mark those methods for you which needs a particular minimum level of SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved that going for exclusion of cases.

But basically the are three main reasons in which you can get this error:

1. (In my case) I was getting the VerifyError all the time that I tried to run my app on devices with API Level under 10 , because I was trying to catch an SQLiteDatabaseLockedException that are supported from the Android API Level 11. So to solve it check that every Exception or possible method (i.e. String.isEmpty() is supported from API Level 9) is supported form your minimum API Level.
2. While I was searching for a solution I found a lot of people that got the VerifyError because there was some problem with Libraries Imports, as explained in this post: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/23/do-not-manually-modify-eclipse-build-path-except-now-r22.html
3. See the sayed.jalil answer.

Hope that will help!

Bye Bye! 
Caterpillar.