# Android database connection error API below 23

Tags: android, database, api

(First of all im not a native english speaker so my english is really bad)

I've been working on a android APP. Basically I need to connect to a SQL Server 2012 express database. All works fine until I use a different API of 23. I've found this error on other topics but no answer worked for me. This is the error:

```
04-08 10:56:06.510 1761-1761/com.example.*****.controlcodigosbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:289)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore
          at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:359)
          at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
          at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:175)
          at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:140)
          at com.example.*****.controlcodigosbox.ConnectionClass.CONN(ConnectionClass.java:32)
          at com.example.*****.controlcodigosbox.MainActivity.onClickRegistrar(MainActivity.java:95)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284) 
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 
          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've been doing some research on the code and the error log and it seems to be an error with the database connection, but i dont really found out what can be.
The thing is, the APP works totally fine on API 23. But when I use an API 17 emulator device this error just appears. I started the project on API 17. I've tried to create an API 10 project and it didn't work.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblCodigo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="@string/introducirCodigo"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCodigo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblCodigo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/edit"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutMuestra"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editCodigo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Material: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblMaterial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gama: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblGama"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ancho: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblAncho"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Diametro: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDiametro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutMuestra"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/seleccionaCantidad"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerBox"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCantidad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerBox"
        android:hint="@string/cantidad"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickRegistrar"
        android:text="@string/darAlta" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the database connection class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionClass {
String ip = "192.168.**.**:1433";
String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
String db = "bd****";
String un = "**";
String password = "******";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnURL = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(classs);
        ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
}
```

And here is the main code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String idDiametro, idMaterial, idAncho, idGama;
private String codigoS;
private LinearLayout layoutMuestra;
private TextView material, diametro, ancho, gama;
private Spinner spinnerBox;
private String[] arrayBox;
private EditText codigo, cantidad;
private ConnectionClass connectionClass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layoutMuestra = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutMuestra);
    spinnerBox = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerBox);
    arrayBox = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arrayBox);
    codigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCodigo);
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    material = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMaterial);
    diametro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDiametro);
    ancho = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAncho);
    gama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblGama);
    cantidad = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCantidad);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡LA PRUEBA BUENA!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adaptador = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.arrayBox, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerBox.setAdapter(adaptador);


    codigo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (codigo.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                layoutMuestra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (codigo.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                layoutMuestra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (codigo.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                layoutMuestra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onClickRegistrar(View v) {
    Boolean visible = true;
    codigoS = codigo.getText().toString();
    if(cantidad.getText().toString().equals("")){
        cantidad.setText("0");
    }
    if (codigo.getText().toString().equals(""))  {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Error! ¡Introduce un código!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (codigo.getText().toString().length() != 15 && codigo.getText().toString().length() != 13){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Error! ¡Introduce un código válido!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        String msg = null;
        //SEPARO EL CODIGO EN LOS RESPECTIVO SUBSTRINGS
        idMaterial = codigoS.substring(2, 3);
        idDiametro = codigoS.substring(3, 7);
        idAncho = codigoS.substring(7, 11);
        idGama = codigoS.substring(11);

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡NO SE HA CONECTADO A LA BD!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                msg = "Error in connection with SQL server";
            } else {
                String query = "select valor from MATERIAL where id='" + idMaterial + "'";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next()){
                    material.setText(rs.getString(1));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡NO HA ENCONTRADO EL MATERIAL!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    visible = false;
                }

                query = "select valor from DIAMETRO where id='" + idDiametro + "'";
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next()){
                    diametro.setText(rs.getString(1));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡NO HA ENCONTRADO EL DIAMETRO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    visible = false;
                }

                query = "select valor from ANCHO where id='" + idAncho + "'";
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next()){
                    ancho.setText(rs.getString(1));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡NO HA ENCONTRADO EL ANCHO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    visible = false;
                }


                query = "select valor from GAMA where id='" + idGama + "'";
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next()){
                    gama.setText(rs.getString(1));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡NO HA ENCONTRADO LA GAMA!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    visible = false;
                }

                if(visible == true){
                    layoutMuestra.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            msg = "Exceptions";
        }
        //GUARDAMOS LOS DATOS EN EL EXCEL
        //OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD DE BOX Y DE UNIDADES
        int cantBox = Integer.parseInt(arrayBox[spinnerBox.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
        int cantUnidad = Integer.parseInt(cantidad.getText().toString());

    }
}

}
```

Im using the last version of `jtds.jdbe` driver.

Comment: Use a click listener instead of onClick via XML

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I strongly advise you not to connect to the database directly from an Android app. Implement a server side API in between.

Comment: IlliegleStateExeception accours when you want to use any object and that object is not in right state. for example. you want to connect to database and database is not opened. check your objects. API 23 includs many dynamic permissions to use objects.

Comment: I changed the onClick propertie to click listener and the first error disspaeared. Now i just have  the `java.lang.VerifyError: net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/TdsCore` error. The logCat makes references to the connection line on the database connection class.. I tried a jdts.jdbe driver lower version but still not working.

Comment: Solved. Changed the onClick propertie and used the ´jtds.jdbc' 1.3.0 driver instead of 1.3.1.