# Getting 'java.lang.VerifyError' on Specific Device (Redmi 4A)

Tags: java, android, verifyerror, redmi-device

I had uploaded my app on google playstore and after some downloads I got the following error in crash report.
Error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl (Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:1208)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1061)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2117)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2249)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:141)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1212)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5113)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

I am  getting this error on Redmi 4A device. I had checked other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror/3549131), but it can't solve this errors. So, can anyone tell me what is the reason for this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share code pointed by line 

at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity (Instrumentation.java:1061)

Comment: How can i navigate to that line? can you please tell me? @ApurvaKolapkar

Comment: `java.lang.VerifyError` can be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/7666442

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Have you tried to add multidex in you app, most probably it will fix

Comment: yes, multidex is already enabled in my app@SG