# Android device issues with only android 4.4 version devices makes my app crashes

Tags: android

When I run my application in android 4.4 - 4.4.x devices my app crashes, but when I run with android 5.0 onwards its working fine.

Crash logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                      
Process: com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp, PID: 18854
  java.lang.VerifyError: com/Forewarn/ForewarnApp/activities/SignInActivity
      at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Application class :

```
public class SoteriaApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AccountUtils.assignContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

I tried with disable instant run from settings and tried with added above attachBaseContext() Method in Application class :

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

I used these libraries in my Gradle:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')

    compile 'com.vdurmont:semver4j:2.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

please find the problem in my code, and already some users also bothered about this issue but No one find out the solution, that's why I again posted my issue.

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: show your log cats of your code

Comment: Post your crash logs.

Comment: Which external library you used in your application & also send your logcat detail.

Comment: yes i updated my crash report. please check it out

Comment: Show me your dependencies which you add in gradle

Comment: Look in logcat, It's probably some method in a java.lang class that is not supported on the android SDK level you are using.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: `retrofit-1.2.2` is released in 2013... You sure you want to use that?

Comment: yes this is my old project , i sure i'm using retrofit 1 in this application

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: probably you are using vector drawables

Comment: if you are using android studio 3.0+ use implementation instead compile, and testImplementation instead of testcompile

Comment: what do you mean by vector drawables ? i just using some of drawables for make user understandable instructions

Comment: @SAM No changes with that implementation instead of compile, still same error.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit i used only image asset drawables

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: Try adding "multiDexEnabled true" in your default config in gradle

Comment: @SachinVarma minSdkVersion 19

Comment: @DeepPatel yes i already defined multiDexEnabled as  true

Comment: Didn't solved my issue yet ? Anymore suggestions ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed My Problem because of some higher level version supported icons i used for lower lever screen's, that's y it's crashed on 4.4 versions phones :

Example : home.png(v21) it is a drawable i used in my app but its applicable and allow to used from android api level 21 onwards only .. that's why crashed on 4.4(api level 19) devices

Comment: I have the exact same problem and this is not the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Remove above code from application class and then try to check whether is working or not

because its working in my project without this bunch of code

so let me know

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the incorrect Multidex configuration. You can try using only `Multidex.install()` in your application. Don't extend the MultiDexApplication. Something like this:

```
public class SoteriaApplication extends Application {

  @Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }

  ...

}
```

and use `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'`

Comment: sorry, no impact with this. it shows same error stiil

Comment: @LaxmanRosy: Then probably your field count is more than the 65k limitation. try adding dexOptions to your android block in your build.gradle `android {
  ...
    dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
  }
  ...
}`

Comment: so much of tired with this issue. still no change same error

Comment: @LaxmanRosy: I once stumbled on the same issue. I fix with the above configuration and something else. Have you check for your drawable whether you make a drawable folder which is not working for Android 4.4. Try moving your drawable files to drawable directory.

Comment: i used all of my drawables from Drawable directory only

Comment: The last attempt you can try is making a clone project then removing all the activity but keep intact the build.gradle and the resource drawable. Then gradually add your activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"  // your package name
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true  // adding multidex support
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  // adding vector drawable support
    }
```

**In Dependencies :**

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

**App Class :**

```
   public class AppClass extends MultiDexApplication {
        public static Context context;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // Your code here
        }
}
```

**Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror) as well**

Comment: yeah no changes with this too. everything i checked but same error

Comment: Please check the link added below the snippet. May be you get a resolution of your issue