# Gradle updation causes Verify error in signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

Verify Error thrown and application crashed during gmail import from back-end. error seemed after Gradle updated from 3.2.0 alpha07 to 3.3.0 alpha13 and distribution url to 4.10.1 . gmail import was working fine before gradle updation.

**Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.envoy.world.Sr due to bad method org.json.JSONObject com.envoy.world.Sr.a(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (declaration of 'com.envoy.world.Sr' appears in /data/app/com.envoy.world.vip2-1/base.apk)**

Comment: Crashed? then there should be a stack trace. Please post that. Also, why are you using the alpha version?

Comment: This might be helpful.take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668788/android-java-lang-verifyerror.you can just go back to stable gradle version check if its work.

Comment: till gradle 3.2.0 alpha07 was worked , but after updation getting the same error mentioned above